# Android SQLiteDatabase is locked

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-asynctask

whenever I use the database I create a new instance of SQLOpenHelper.

I have a screen A that has a method that uses readableDatabase () in onResume (). In the screen B when it starts one AsyncTask that calls a method that uses writeableDatabase ().

If the thread ends after closing the display screen B then A can not access the database. So I get SQLitedatabase is locked.

So what I have to do?

Comment: By screen A & B do you mean Activities, or what...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to release the database before attempting to establish another connection, or share the connection.